# How to parse a postal address

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an Indian address that I need to parse in order to get the various components i.e. City, state, pin code, house number, etc.

The problem with Indian addresses is that there is no fixed format. You might or might not find commas dividing the various parts of the address. So it becomes problematic to parse the address where the states have names that have spaces in them.

Sample data is as follows:

1. PNB Building,
   4th Floor, 5 Wallace Street,
   Fort Mumbai,
   Mumbai - 400001
   Maharashtra,
   India
2. Steel Authority of India Ltd.
   Ispat Bhavan
   Lodhi Road
   NEW DELHI
   110003
   INDIA

Comment: Divide your address into parts like Street name,State,District

Comment: Why do you need to parse the address?

Comment: Are there things you can be sure of their format? For example, would the post code have a fixed format? It will probably be very difficult to do anyway automatically if you addresses don't have fixed formatting.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar dividing the address into parts would be difficult since not all addresses have Street names or the same format for state names.

Comment: @eggyal I am trying to develop a tool to parse Addresses as read by an OCR reader to sort mail.

Comment: @Gimly the only thing I can be sure of is the pin code format, the country name and the state name. The main problem is in the street names and how to differentiate between different parts of the address and states with two words.

Comment: @poorvagupta: In that case, surely all you need is to locate the postal code (a simple regex should suffice) and sort based on that?